# Python Regex Matching characters

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to learn Python regular expressions. I have a long string that contains many patterns that look like: `#v=xxxxxxxxxx` where x is the variable characters I want.

I was thinking I could use `re.findall(r'...', myString)` where `...` is my pattern. That's the part I'm having trouble with. I somehow need to get the next 10 characters after each `#v=`.

All help is appreciated :)

Comment: Please give some complete example data and show us what code you have so far!

Comment: What regular expression(s) have you tried?

Comment: `r'#v={10}'` doesn't work at all :/

Comment: Try `re.findall(r'#v=(.{10})', str)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close! Here's an RE that'll work:

```
In [1]: import re

In [2]: s = "#v=yyyyyyyyyy #v=xxxxxxxxxx #v=zzzzzzzzzz"

In [3]: re.findall(r'#v=(\w{10})', s)
Out[3]: ['yyyyyyyyyy', 'xxxxxxxxxx', 'zzzzzzzzzz']
```